# Any risk of email configured for pop/imap access?

Tags: mobile, attack-vector

If my mobile phone is infected with some malware and the only connection I have to my corporate network is that the email client in the phone is configured for mail (pop/imap), what would be the risk of getting my corporate network compromised ?

---

Or, what would be the attack vector for an attacker who wants to compromise a corporate network, but the only connection between him and the network is a phone with an email client.
(mobile phone does not connect to the business network or wifi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it's high risk, but not necessarily for the reasons you think.

If an attacker gains access to your emails, the easiest attack vector is to find every email address possible, then email them pretending to be you, and attach some malware to the email.

Malware-attached-to-emails is the oldest trick in the book, and still one of the most effective. It's how [Cryptolocker](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/cryptolocker-is-the-nastiest-malware-ever-heres-what-you-can-do/) is spreading, and [many high profile hacks](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/07/email-based-malware-attacks-july-2012/) used this method.